# New-Item: Access Denied

Tags: powershell, credentials

I am still very new to Powershell and I figured this would be an easy task. For my job I need to create a set of folders, over and over again and at this point I'm tired of doing this with a mouse when I could automate the task and move on to more pressing issues. Below is a sample of what I'm trying to do.

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$Test1 = Test-Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Inetpub\wwwroot\MAKEthisFOLDER"

if ($test1 -eq $false) {
    new-item "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Inetpub\wwwroot\MAKEthisFOLDER" -ItemType Directory -Credential $cred
}

else {
    Write-Host "Folder already exists" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor red 
}
```

I figured I could pass my credentials to new-item and have it create the directories. Instead I receive an error, which will be listed below. If I try to run this script without specifying credentials, then I get the second error listed.

**First error:**

> The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive
>   cmdlet. Perform the  operation again without specifying credentials.

**Second error:**

> New-item : Access to the path 'MAKEthisFOLDER' is denied.

I know this is incredibly simple but any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your current user account have privileges to make the change to that destination?  If so, there's no need to specify `-Credential`

Comment: If your account does not have access to that location, I'd suggest passing `-Credential $cred` to `Test-Path` as well or that will error out with access denied.

Comment: @iRon `env:` is a drive yes, but invoking a variable from that drive is just a string.  `$env:HomeDrive.GetType() => System.String`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `New-PSDrive` and assign credentials to it like:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$Test1 = Test-Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Inetpub\wwwroot\MAKEthisFOLDER"

if ($test1 -eq $false) {
    $homedrive = $env:HOMEDRIVE
    New-PSDrive -Name $homedrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\Inetpub\wwwroot\MAKEthisFOLDER" -Credential $cred
    new-item "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Inetpub\wwwroot\MAKEthisFOLDER" -ItemType Directory
}
else {
Write-Host "Folder already exists" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor red }
```

This is pending the folder exists.

Comment: New-PSDrive : Cannot process the drive name because the drive name contains one or more of the following characters that are not valid: ; ~ / \ . :

Answer (score 0):

If your user account has access to the locations specified, there is no need to specify the credential.  If it is, however, you should also be passing the credential to `Test-Path` to have a valid response.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Path = "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Inetpub\wwwroot\MAKEthisFOLDER"

If (-not (Test-Path -Path $Path -Credential $Credential -PathType 'Container'))
{
    ## -Force creates the folder structure if it doesn't exist
    New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType 'Directory' -Credential $Credential -Force
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "'$Path' already exists" -ForegroundColor 'Yellow' -BackgroundColor 'Red'
}
```

An alternative (that should work regardless of other factors)

```
New-PSDrive -Name 'INET' -PSProvider 'FileSystem' -Root "$env:HomeDrive\Inetpub\wwwroot" -Credential (Get-Credential)
If (-not (Test-Path -Path 'INET:\MAKEthisFOLDER'))
{
    New-Item -Path 'INET:\MAKEthisFOLDER' -ItemType 'Directory'
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "Folder already exists" -ForegroundColor 'Yellow' -BackgroundColor 'Red'
}
Remove-PSDrive -Name 'INET'
```

Comment: `Test-Path -Path $Path -Credential $Credential` returns his first error about the FileSystem provider

Comment: @Jelphy Assuming defaults, `$env:HOMEDRIVE` resolves to `C:` or `D:` literal strings.  If he's making a script, he should be explicitly defining arguments so cryptic messages like this don't happen.  It would be VERY weird if those are not mapped drives.